# What is wrong with my Oracle View?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

```
CREATE VIEW Tournament_Winners AS
SELECT tournament_no, player_no FROM Results WHERE position = 1
SELECT tornament_name FROM Tournament WHERE Tournamnet.tournament_no = Results.tournament_no;
```

I have also tried to implement this using a JOIN:

```
SELECT tournament_no, player_no FROM Results WHERE position = 1
FULL JOIN Tournament
ON Tournament.tournament_no = Results.tournament_no;
```

Neither works.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: I see from the answers below that I was following the wrong syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at syntax of [joins](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B13916_04/joins.htm) and [view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_8004.htm).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Tournament_Winners AS
      SELECT a.tournament_no, a.player_no, b.tornament_name
         FROM Results a,Tournament b 
            where a.tournament_no=b.tournament_no and a.position=1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st 2 results in one view doens't work

for the second, you Need to work on your syntax/order

```
SELECT
FROM 
WHERE
GROUP BY
ORDER BY
HAVING

SELECT tournament_no, player_no 
FROM Results 
FULL JOIN Tournament
ON Tournament.tournament_no = Results.tournament_no
WHERE position = 1
```